# MySQL - How do I make a partition for every data that is not predefined by current partitions?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

MySQL 5.7

---

**Question** -
Can I make a table partition for every data that does not fit to any of predefined partitions?  Or is it against the purpose of the partitioning concept?

for example,

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(GROUP_CODE)(
PARTITION A_001 IN ('A001'),
PARTITION B_101 VALUES IN ('B101'),
PARTITION B_102 VALUES IN ('B102'),
PARTITION B_202 VALUES IN ('B202'),
PARTITION C_101 IN ('C101'),
PARTITION C_201 IN ('C201'),
PARTITION D_000 IN ('D000'),
);
```

If I make partitions as such, 'G525' won't be allowed to added to the table. If the partitioning key was integer I can go for the RANGE, but is it possible with the LIST?

Comment: 'Unlike the case with RANGE partitioning, there is no “catch-all” such as MAXVALUE; all expected values for the partitioning expression should be covered in PARTITION ... VALUES IN (...) clauses.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-list.html

Comment: Cannot be solved in single INSERT. You must solve this in stored procedure which will check the value to be inserted and, if needed, SP should alter the structure and add a partition. From the other side this needs in client-code DDL which is bad practice. Think about partitioning by the prefix letter and subpartitioning by postfix number.

Comment: `PARTITION BY LIST` is unlikely to provide any performance benefit over a suitable written `INDEX`.